# Can the array's default pointer be changed in anyways?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

void change(int (*arr)[10]){
  // manipulate
}

int main(){
  int arrM[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
  change(&arrM)
}
```

I am aware that the arrM is a constant pointer and cannot be changed or assigned and also that it cannot be passed as a pointer to pointer like **argv since it degrades to a pointer from an array and not a pointer to pointer. But my question is "Is this the way the design goes so as to protect the array's initial memory from not getting overwritten(if yes the how?) or is there a mechanism that can get into the //manipulate region that can change the constant pointer arrM's value"

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Comment: No, it cannot be done in C.

Comment: If you really want to try to change `arrM` then you should pass `&arrM` to your `change()` function.

Comment: thanks self MadHatter for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am aware that the arrM is a constant pointer and cannot be changed
>   or assigned

An array name (arrM), should not be considered as a pointer, and thinking of it as a const type is going too far.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351544/is-array-name-a-constant-pointer-in-c), pretty much answers your question.

> Is this the way the design goes so as to protect the array's initial
>   memory from not getting overwritten(if yes the how?) or is there a
>   mechanism that can get into the //manipulate region that can change
>   the constant pointer arrM's value

The array's initial memory is not being "protected". You can declare a pointer, to point to the array's first element, and use pointer arithmetic to "overwrite" the array.

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that the arrM is a constant pointer

No, an array is not a constant pointer. An array is a different type. There are cases where an array decays or is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, e.g. when an array is passed to a function, but this does not mean an array is a constant pointer.

> Is this the way the design goes so as to protect the array's initial
>   memory from not getting overwritten(if yes the how?) or is there a
>   mechanism that can get into the //manipulate region that can change
>   the constant pointer arrM's value

A variable is a location in memory which can store a value and is referenced by an indentifier which is the variable's name. When a variable is defined, space is allocated for it (during run-time, of course) and the indentifier is made to refer to the location, i.e., the identifier is bound to that location. The identifier will always refer to that location throughout its lifetime.  You cannot rebind the indentifier to a different memory location. You can change the value of the variable, i.e., value stored in the location referenced by the variable's name but that's a different matter. This is true of any variable type, not just an array.

What this means is any variable is allocated space either on the stack (automatic storage allocation) or in text or data segment (static storage allocation) of the program's memory space. You cannot bind the variable to a different address later.

Comment: do you mean that we can't generalize what applies to the single dimensional array like int a[10], where 'a' can be thought of as a constant pointer to int

Comment: @muru First of all, `a` is not a constant pointer, it's an array. Second, a variable is a location in memory. That location has a name, i.e., an identifier which is the variable's name. The identifier always refers that location throughout its lifetime. You cannot bind it to different location in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of arrM as a pointer.  It helps instead to think of it as a constant integer-like thing whose value is the compiler-assigned address of the array.  It makes no more sense to take the address of arrM than to take the address of the constant 5.  Likewise, it makes no more sense to change the value of arrM than it would to change the value of 5.

Comment: 5 here means an integer constant ?